# Need help in moving the records of normalized database to another database and store in de-normalized form

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cron-task

I am very new to Mysql and do not have any experience in writing stored procedures/functions. i know only basic SQL queries and worked mainly in oracle.
Now i have a task to generate reports based on a data model.

Since the data model is little complex and its a normalized one with more than 18 tables and connected with foreign key constraints we would like to move the older records to another database for reporting purpose.

I would like to know how to move the records of one database(with 18 tables-normalized one) to another reporting server but store in denormalized form so its easier for me to write queries. otherwise i may need to write join queries on 18 tables.

and also moving the records must be done on a daily basis. like a cron job that move the old records to reporting server. how to configure this?

how to write stored procedure?

Comment: You would start by determining which DBMS you are using. You have tagged both MySql and SqlServer. They are not the same thing. Then for anybody to actually be able to help you need to provide some details. As posted this is impossible to answer.

Comment: No matter which DBMS he uses, he will probably still have _"write join queries on 18 tables"_ to denormalize the data for export.

Comment: @Uueerdo, it is a good habit to be clear and accurate on tags, specially for new users. I usually do advice in comments .

Comment: This question is much too broad for SO. I'm voting to close it as such. Just the same, OP, at some point you will have to write the `join` statements to bring this data together into a denormalized form for reporting and you will have to do ETL to get it from one server to another. Whether you denormalize before or after ETL is up to you.

Comment: @FLICKER agreed, just trying to give the little advice that can be had with the information they did provide.

Comment: HI All,i deleted the mysql server tag.

Comment: supposing , if i want to move the all 18 tables (normalized form) as is to another server on a periodic basis, how do i do tat? forget about denormalizing.

Comment: a) You said you deleted the mysql server tag, but it is still there - what dbms IS your server? b) What dbms is the reporting server? c) Do you want to delete the older data on your original server and just keep it on the reporting server?

Comment: @Solarflare- Both original server and reporting server will be MYSQL. yes. i want to delete the older data in original server and move them to reporting server.

Comment: i want to move the entire database structure(records) from original server(it has 18 tables with foreign key constraints) to the reporting server.

Comment: Your approach is not easy. You have to keep track of which data to move, which to copy, which to update, which changes in the main db may have impact on archive data that is not present anymore (e.g. a change in reference data), and in which order to do it and then execute it. There are some ways/tools you can use, maybe as a beginner get a consultant to help you decide and set it up. I probably would do: move data on same database to archive table including foreign keys (script or pt-archiver), and replication/mysqldump to the reporting server, though im not sure why you need a 2nd server.